# Want to change just the letter v in mathprint

Tags: fonts, math-fonts, libertine

With the font packages I am using there is only one letter that looks bad to me in mathprint. It's the letter $v$. What I want is to type just $v$ and have the italicized text version of "v" appear instead of the mathprint version (no change to the document's font). I found that using

\mathcode`v=`v

allows me to change the mathprint $v$ into the nice textprint "v" in the same font, but the text "v" doesn't flow with the rest of the letters in mathprint. Hence the desire for the italicized version of the text "v". Sadly,

\mathcode`v=`{\it v}

does not work. Does anyone know how to change a letter in mathprint to the italics text version of itself, without changing the font.

Here is a png illustrating what I have and want

[image]

Here is a snippet of MWE code with a deletable % that will compile the above picture into pdf

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% \mathcode`v=`v
% Erase the "%" before \mathcode to see bad v become current v but not good v

\begin{document}

\underline{Packages used:}\vspace{0.1cm}

libertine

[libertine]{newtxmath}

[T1]{fontenc}\vspace{-0.5cm}

\begin{align*}
    \text{What I do not like} \leadsto \text{Text: v} \hspace{0.3cm} \& \hspace{0.3cm} \text{Math, bad: } &v\\
    \text{Using mathcode`v=`v} \leadsto \text{Text: v} \hspace{0.3cm} \& \hspace{0.3cm} \text{Math, text: } &v \\
    \text{What I want} \leadsto \text{Text: v} \hspace{0.3cm} \& \hspace{0.3cm} \text{Math, good: } & {\it v}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Just be careful and never use `\nu`.  The shape of the Greek letter is the reason for the choice of the curly italic "v" for math.

Comment: Good point. There are barely different. Perhaps it would be nice to pull a single letter for v from a different font instead. I just figured it would be easier to not change fonts and i don't use \nu for much that would involve using v alongside it in a confusing manner.

Comment: It's not so much about when you use "v" and `\nu` next to one another, but when you use them both in the same document, and they can appear separately in possibly ambiguous contexts.  Which is meant?  Say it's in an engineering spec for a bridge.  A misreading could mean the difference between a safe structure and a disaster.